# Can not display specific character from model in Class Library ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application which have the hierarchy like this:

[image]

Inside the `CustomerModel.cs` file, I have a field that I want to bind to a text box for input:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Le nom de la société est obligatoire")]
[Display(Name = "Raison sociale")]
public string Company { get; set; }
```

What I have done in view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Company, new { @class = "input" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Company, "", new { @class="has-text-danger" })
```

The problem is: Title and validation message are rendered correctly in development mode, but when I deploy the application to Azure, some specific character in the title and validation message is not rendered correctly. In this case the character `é`.

[image]

I have already used `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in my `_Layout.cshtml` but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea what causes the problem and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same problem with file encoding. Check file encoding for CustomerModel.cs, it must be utf-8 too. I used notepad++ for this.